# Old phone to track my bike in case of theft

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, sim-card, google-maps, geolocation

I have an old galaxy s3, I was thinking of storing it in my bike seat or a lockbox on my bike in case it gets stolen so i can track down my bike. Is there any way of doing this without a sim card(phone works without one) or a sim card without data, just minutes? I live in Canada and the cheapest simcard with a dataplan i can find is 711 speakout for$10 a month. Im looking to spend less than that, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is your stolen bike more valuable than the trade-in value  of the phone and the cost of the plan for tracking.

Comment: Plus you'd most likely have to charge it on a daily basis. That being said, this question doesn't seem to be Android specific. You might have better luck asking on [Bicycles](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @wbogacz yes it is, I really dont get why people post these none answers.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to use avast! Anti-Theft which allows you to text `1234 LOCATE` to your phone in order to locate it, replacing 1234 with your avast! PIN number.